# How can I calculate $\mathbf{X}\mathbf{X}^{\rm T} \mathbf{v}$ in the most effective way without storing $\mathbf{X}\mathbf{X}^{\rm T}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I have a matrix $\mathbf{X} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$ and a vector $\mathbf{v} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ with $n \gg m$. I would like to compute $\mathbf{X}\mathbf{X}^{\rm T} \mathbf{v}$ in the most effective way, but I cannot store $\mathbf{X} \mathbf{X}^{\rm T}$. Do you have an idea how to perform these multiplications as fast as possible? Of course, some partial results (like some rows of $\mathbf{X} \mathbf{X}^{\rm T}$) can be temporarily stored.

Comment: Sanity check: are you allowed to only store $\boldsymbol{X}$ and compute the two matrix vector products $\boldsymbol{X}^Tv $ and $\boldsymbol{X} (\boldsymbol{X}^Tv)$

Comment: Yes, that is what I have done so far. But this does not exploit cache tiling (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18410162/dgemm-or-dgemv-for-matrix-multiplication). Do you think this there won't be better way to do these multiplications?

Comment: What is the programming environment as this is not a math question, but a programming question on how to be memory efficient with $${\bf u} = {\bf X} \left( {\bf X}^\intercal {\bf v} \right)$$

Comment: @John Alexiou It is Fortran and I am trying to use LAPACK subroutines to do the job efficiently.

Comment: Related: https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/cublas-strided-batched-matrix-multiply/

Comment: @JohnAlexiou Thanks for the link. I will go through this material.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So what is the issue with this sample Fortran code? Each item in the loop is a `dot_product()` really and can be handled with the `BLAS` Level 1 routine `DOT`, or the whole loop with `BLAS` Level 2 routine `GEMV`.

```
function CalcProjection(X,v) result(u)
!tex: Calculates the product $u = X (X^\intercal v)$
!
!
real, intent(in) :: v(:), X(:,:)
real :: u(size(X,1)), w(size(X,2))
integer :: i,g,n,m
n = size(X,1)
m = size(X,2)
do g=1,m
    w(g)=sum(X(:,g)*v(:))
end do
do i=1,n
    u(i)=sum(X(i,:)*w(:))
end do    

end function
```

that is called like

```
! Variables
integer, parameter :: n = 100, m = 35
real :: v(n), X(n,m), u(n), e(n)
integer :: i,g

! Body of FortranConsole2

call RANDOM_SEED()
call RANDOM_NUMBER(v)
call RANDOM_NUMBER(X) 

u = CalcProjection(X,v)

print *, sum( abs(matmul(X, matmul(transpose(X),v)) - u))
```

and returns

```
  0.0000000E+00
```

which means the calculation is done correctly.

---

As a partitioned matrix, the above can be constructed as

$$\begin{aligned}\begin{bmatrix}\boldsymbol{u}_{1}\\
\boldsymbol{u}_{2}
\end{bmatrix} & =\begin{bmatrix}\boldsymbol{X}_{11} & \boldsymbol{X}_{12}\\
\boldsymbol{X}_{21} & \boldsymbol{X}_{22}
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\boldsymbol{X}_{11}^{\intercal} & \boldsymbol{X}_{21}^{\intercal}\\
\boldsymbol{X}_{12}^{\intercal} & \boldsymbol{X}_{22}^{\intercal}
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\boldsymbol{v}_{1}\\
\boldsymbol{v}_{2}
\end{bmatrix}\end{aligned}
$$

with possibly parallelizable solution

$$\begin{aligned}\boldsymbol{s}_{1} & =\boldsymbol{X}_{11}^{\intercal}\boldsymbol{v}_{1}+\boldsymbol{X}_{21}^{\intercal}\boldsymbol{v}_{2}\\
\boldsymbol{s}_{2} & =\boldsymbol{X}_{12}^{\intercal}\boldsymbol{v}_{1}+\boldsymbol{X}_{22}^{\intercal}\boldsymbol{v}_{2}\\
\begin{bmatrix}\boldsymbol{u}_{1}\\
\boldsymbol{u}_{2}
\end{bmatrix} & =\begin{bmatrix}\boldsymbol{X}_{11}\boldsymbol{s}_{1}+\boldsymbol{X}_{12}\boldsymbol{s}_{2}\\
\boldsymbol{X}_{21}\boldsymbol{s}_{1}+\boldsymbol{X}_{22}\boldsymbol{s}_{2}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{aligned}$$

where $\boldsymbol{s}_1$ and $\boldsymbol{s}_2$ are computed in parallel.

But note that $ \boldsymbol{A}^\intercal \boldsymbol{x} = (\boldsymbol{x} \boldsymbol{A})^\intercal $ and if $\boldsymbol{x}$ is vector then we can ignore the transpose, the above is simplified to

$$\begin{aligned}\boldsymbol{s}_{1} & =\boldsymbol{v}_{1}\boldsymbol{X}_{11}+\boldsymbol{v}_{2}\boldsymbol{X}_{21}\\
\boldsymbol{s}_{2} & =\boldsymbol{v}_{1}\boldsymbol{X}_{12}+\boldsymbol{v}_{2}\boldsymbol{X}_{22}
\end{aligned}$$

which has the advantage of *not having to calculate* the transpose of the matrix in memory.

Comment: Thanks for this code. That's exactly what I have done so far. However, row-column products seems to be slow when I try to parallelize the code with OpenMP. So I wanted to reduce CPU time at a moderate expense of memory usage. I can store say 1000 $\mathbb{R}^n$ vectors in RAM in addition to $\mathbf{v}$ and $\mathbf{X}, and so that would be good to exploit.

Comment: You can partition the matrix $X$` and the vector $v$ into and split into threads, but I am pretty sure `GEMV` can act in parallel automatically.

Comment: Yeah, but GEMV is not much better than sequential DOT calls, is it? It is said that DEMM should be more effective.

Comment: I have never heard of `DEMM`. Sorry. I did see https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/pro-tip-cublas-strided-batched-matrix-multiply/148513 somewhere midpage mentioning it.

Comment: This routine performs matrix-matrix multiplications (supposedly via Strassen's algorithm).